# Why dockerfile ENV cannot override $PATH for non-root user?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I want to install miniconda in ubuntu docker image for a non-root user. So far the installation part is successful but I cannot add the path of conda to the environment variable `$PATH` of that user. I tried to achieve that with docker `ENV`. Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y openssh-server sudo

RUN useradd -rm -d /home/devp -s /bin/bash -g root -G sudo -u 1000 devp && \
 echo 'devp:devp11' | chpasswd && \
 adduser devp sudo

WORKDIR /home/devp

USER devp
RUN wget \
    https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh \
    && mkdir ~/.conda \
    && bash Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -b \
    && rm -f Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh 
ENV PATH=/home/devp/miniconda3/bin:${PATH}
ARG PATH=/home/devp/miniconda3/bin:${PATH}
#RUN conda env create --quiet -n env1 --file env1.yml

USER root

RUN mkdir /var/run/sshd
RUN service ssh start
EXPOSE 22

CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd","-D"]
```

I ran docker with `docker run --name img -p 10022:22 -d img:tag`

For my root user, `$PATH` is overridden

```
/home/devp/miniconda3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

For my non-root user, `$PATH` is not overridden when I `ssh devp@x.x.x.x -p 10022 'echo $PATH'`

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

I have 2 questions:

1. How can I override `$PATH` for non-root user?
2. Why `ENV` does not work for non-root user?

Comment: If you `docker run --rm -u devp your-image sh -c 'echo $PATH'`, does it in fact return that second value?  Or are you doing something else to verify the `$PATH`?

Comment: @DavidMaze your code does return the overridden `$PATH`! But I got the second value by 1) `docker run --name img -p 10022:22 -d img:tag` 2) `ssh devp@x.x.x.x -p 10022`

Comment: That sounds like a system-administration question, for how to set up the dotfiles for your ssh daemon, and not really a programming problem.  Remember that a container is a wrapper around a single process, not a VM; IME it's unusual to run sshd in a container and its very difficult to set up securely (your Dockerfile already has two significant security issues).

Comment: Thank you for the advice! Now I realized that running ssh server inside a docker image is insecure and not recommended. But you mentioned there are 2 two security issues in my Dockerfile, could you also tell me what is the other issue?

Comment: Hard-coding a password and giving your "non-root" user unrestricted sudo privileges are the two things that jumped out at me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference here stems not from *root vs. non-root user* but from how the process is started, i.e., *directly by docker vs. via ssh login*.

With the `ENV` directive you specify environment variables which will be set by `docker` for processes started inside the container. But when logging in via `ssh` the new shell presented to you is a *login shell* started by the `ssh` daemon.

But `ssh` clears and resets most of the environment variables before starting the login shell. Additionally the login shell usually reads some config files to setup it's own environment and `PATH` is almost always one of the configured environment variables.

So to change `PATH` for shells started via `ssh` you must configure this in the `sshd_config` or via the user's login shell configs, e.g., `/etc/profile`, `~/.bashrc` etc.

See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38175/difference-between-login-shell-and-non-login-shell

---

But as [David Maze said in the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73642794/why-dockerfile-env-cannot-override-path-for-non-root-user#comment130053781_73642794): using a `sshd` inside docker container is discouraged. Containers are not VMs and are instead meant to only run a single process/application.

So depending on your use case there is probably a cleaner solution using the containers *the docker way*!